# about Paths or Nodes, agent detour

Tags: path, nodes, anylogic

Is there a way to block certain Paths or Nodes with Statechart, and detour?

I'm curious about the able to restrict access to certain Paths or Nodes, detour car to other Paths.
I think it's possible with the Transporter Control block
Is there a way to connect Statechart with the car Agent?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nVwd.png)

Comment: Not easy to do... but here it's done: https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/a8cb1aaa-1113-4122-8865-d8cf0a43077e?mode=SETTINGS